# How to add new attribute to the <form> using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

i am getting full form here from my other file in **queryString** var.. now i want to add **method="POST"** in side form tag

```
  var queryString = document.getElementById("render").value;
```

i tried with some possibilities like .attr, .append but didn't work...

my form samle/skalaton code which i am getting from file is ...

```
     <form class="form-horizontal">
      <fieldset>

       <!-- Form Name -->
        <legend>Form Name</legend>

      </fieldset>
     </form>
```

can anyone tell me how to do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this maybe -

```
queryString = queryString.replace('<form','<form method="POST" ');
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this 1:-

```
$(".form-horizontal").attr("method","post");
```

Comment: check by Inspect Element whether this attribute is added or not to Form?

Answer (score 1):

The `.attr()` method should work. With this function you can set any attribute of an element.

```
$(".form-horizontal").attr("method", "post");
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/KCMXW/

Comment: i mean i getting <form></form> from other file and i am retriving it here so i won't be available in DOM

Answer (score 0):

Try this JS (Without using jquery library) soln

```
document.querySelectorAll('.form-horizontal')[0].setAttribute("method","post");
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nhbkX/)**

Comment: if you are not willing to use jquery,then this solution will work for you.

Comment: i am trying your solution only

Comment: does your DOM (<form ...) exist ? one suggestion use this JS script after DOM gets loaded,